# Sending parameters to make (Linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, makefile

See the code below: How do I send a parameter BASE_NAME = myfile to the command line without typing BASE_NAME. I want to enter only

$make pdf myfile

```
BASE_NAME = myfile

LATEX     = latex
PDFLATEX  = pdflatex
BIBTEX    = bibtex
MAKEINDEX = makeindex
DVIPS     = dvips
PS2PDF    = ps2pdf

pdf: $(BASE_NAME).pdf
ps: $(BASE_NAME).ps

$(BASE_NAME).ps: $(BASE_NAME).tex 
    $(LATEX) $<
    $(BIBTEX) $(BASE_NAME) 
    $(LATEX) $< 
    $(LATEX) $<
    $(DVIPS) -Ppdf $(BASE_NAME)

$(BASE_NAME).pdf: $(BASE_NAME).tex
    $(PDFLATEX) $<

clean:
    rm -f $(BASE_NAME)*.ps $(BASE_NAME)*.dvi *.log \
          *.aux *.blg *.toc \
          missfont.log $(BASE_NAME)*.bbl $(BASE_NAME)*.out \
          $(BASE_NAME)*.lof $(BASE_NAME)*.lot

open:
    acroread $(BASE_NAME).pdf
```

Also, how do I use an option-type
$make pdf -o myfile
to generate the pdf and then open it from the option -o

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pattern-rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) in such a way that your target is the name of your file.  The $@ variable would then contain the name of the file.

```
%.pdf:

        @echo $@;
```

-

```
$ make hello.pdf
hello.pdf
```

-

```
$ make path/to/hello.pdf
path/to/hello.pdf
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand. It did not work. Or did I do wrong? I edit the file and digit ``make hello.pdf``. But not work.

Comment: follow the link to documentation. Read it carefully. Use `make --debug=b`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want. You could do your shell script which do that: you'll type `mymake pdf myfile`, and your `mymake` shell script would run `make pdf BASE_NAME=myfile`