# Sending parameters to make (Linux or other *nix flavor)

Tags: linux, makefile

See the code below: How do I send a parameter `BASE_NAME = myfile` to the command line without typing `BASE_NAME`. I want to enter only

```
$make pdf myfile
```

```
BASE_NAME = myfile

LATEX     = latex
PDFLATEX  = pdflatex
BIBTEX    = bibtex
MAKEINDEX = makeindex
DVIPS     = dvips
PS2PDF    = ps2pdf

pdf: $(BASE_NAME).pdf
ps: $(BASE_NAME).ps

$(BASE_NAME).ps: $(BASE_NAME).tex 
    $(LATEX) $<
    $(BIBTEX) $(BASE_NAME) 
    $(LATEX) $< 
    $(LATEX) $<
    $(DVIPS) -Ppdf $(BASE_NAME)

$(BASE_NAME).pdf: $(BASE_NAME).tex
    $(PDFLATEX) $<

clean:
    rm -f $(BASE_NAME)*.ps $(BASE_NAME)*.dvi *.log \
          *.aux *.blg *.toc \
          missfont.log $(BASE_NAME)*.bbl $(BASE_NAME)*.out \
          $(BASE_NAME)*.lof $(BASE_NAME)*.lot

open:
    acroread $(BASE_NAME).pdf
```

Also, how do I use an option-type

```
$make pdf -o myfile
```

to generate the PDF and then open it from the option `-o`?

Comment: This is off topic in my opinion. While Makefiles are used by some TeX users, expertise in TeX and expertise in Makefiles do not correspond. I suggest migration to another site (perhaps SuperUser?).

Comment: @JosephWright I do not agree: TeX-related Makefiles have their own specific features, like the trick with checking whether another compilation run is necessary.

Comment: @Boris: But this question is not about checking whether another compilation run is necessary but how to pass arguments and options to make. And IMHO this is off topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending parameters to make (Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186502/sending-parameters-to-make-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a TeX question *per se,* but nevertheless...

You are much better if you specifiy generic rules instead of specific ones.  Besides, if you want to open your files, `Makefile` conventions suggest the command `make open` rather than `make -o`.

I usually do it like this

```
# The only thing that changes!
TEXFILES = firstfile.tex secondfile.tex  

PDFS = ${TEXFILES:%.tex=%.pdf}

all: $(PDFS)

open: all
    for x in ${PDFS}; do (xpdf $$x &); done

# You can write a similar rule for ps...
%.pdf: %.tex  
    pdflatex $*
    -bibtex $*
    pdflatex $*
    - while ( grep -q '^LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed' $*.log || \
    grep -q '^Package natbib Warning: Citation(s) may have changed' $*.log ) \
    do pdflatex $*; done


clean:
   $(RM) *.aux *.bbl *.dvi *.log *.out *.toc *.blg *.lof *.lot

distclean: clean
       $(RM) $(PDFS)
```

Comment: You need to convert the white spaces in the beginning to TABs: I do not know how to put TABs in SX input fields :(

Comment: Now ``make open`` and error: for x in ${PDFS}; do acroread $$x &; done /bin/sh: Syntax error: ";" unexpected make: ** [open] Erro 2

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: this does not work with & :(.  The right line is `for x in ${PDFS}; do acroread $$x ; done`

Comment: Another way is to put the call into a subshell:  `for x in ${PDFS}; do (acroread $$x &) ; done`.  I still remember my Unix basics - but sometimes it takes time  :)

Comment: Thanks @Boris. And i discovered Rubber https://launchpad.net/rubber install rubber and digit rubber -d myfile for generate pdf file and rubber --clean myfile for clear aux files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your `Makefile` as Boris wrote:

```
%.pdf: %.tex
     pdflatex $<
```

After you can run `make myfile.pdf` or `make foo.pdf` or anything else.